# Performance : Laptop HDD or Desktop HDD?

Tags: hard-drive, laptop

I am about to purchase a new 4TB HDD for my PC. What are difference if I use laptop 2.5 hdd's in Desktop PC?

- What are differences in their performance?
- Are significant power-usage differences, in i.e. 24hrs/year turned on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 2.5" laptop HDD USUALLY spins at 5,400RPM, whereas a 3.5" desktop HDD USUALLY spins at 7,200RPM. The slower rotation speed in a laptop drive is therefore (roughly) 25% less performant. Add to that a desktop HDD will have a larger cache, which increases read and write performance.

Note: I say USUALLY in the above as you can buy 7200 2.5" drives, but they're expensive. You can also by 10,000RPM desktop drives, but again they're more expensive.

With respect to power consumption, I don't know the stats but given laptops are designed to run off a battery I suspect they're more energy efficient.

Comment: Laptop platters are much smaller in size, so 5400 rotational speed is not a consequence. Western digital back in the day sold Raptor line of fast drives that were a 2.5 drive in a 3.5 case. SSD changed everything.

Comment: @Moab that being said, i've always found read/write on 2.5" 5,400 rpm laptop drives to be much less performant than on a desktop 7,200 drive performing similar activities.

Comment: You need to provide data to support your claim. Drive cache can also be a significant factor.